# How can I add custom apps to Sleep focus allowed apps?

Tags: macos, applications, settings, ventura, focus

How can I add a custom app that is not available on the list of apps to add to sleep focus? I'm on Macos Ventura 13.4

Comment: You mean Do Not Disturb maybe?

Comment: no I was thinking of downtime. I added it to the list of apps and it works now

Comment: Could you post an answer to help others having the same question as you find an answer. (I can also answer if you want)

Comment: by list of apps I mean I went to system settings > screen time> always allowed > and set the apps I want to always have access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow certain apps during Down Time, go to *System Settings > Screen Time > Always Allowed*. Select the applications you always want to allow. All the apps should be there. If they aren't, a simple restart may bring them up.

[image]

See [Choose always allowed apps in Screen Time on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl4949e9f4/mac) for more info and guidance on this.